# AWK not printing variable inside square brackets

Tags: variables, printing, awk

### I have a bash script that in the crucial part goes like this:

```
#!/bin/sh


read IP (Example: 192.168.2.46)

var1= $IP 


awk -v var="$var1" 'NR==3{print "      \"server\": [ \"var:666\" ]"}7' /home/mark/server.conf > /home/mark/tmp && mv -f /home/mark/tmp /home/mark/server.conf
```

---

The desired output is:

```
"server": [ "192.168.2.46:666" ]
```

However, I'm getting:

```
"server": [ "var1:666" ]
```

Why, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the awk variable `var` outside the double quotes.

```
awk -v var="$var1" 'NR==3{print "      \"server\": [ \""var":666\" ]"}7'
```

Example:

```
$ var1="123"
$ echo '1' | awk -v var="$var1" '/1/{print "foo\""var"\"bar"}'
foo"123"bar
```